# vis-timeline on meteor doesn't render

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to use properly the vis-timeline library on my Meteor application, but it doesn't render.

This is my .html file

```
<template name="kk">
<div class="ui huge segment" id="visualization">
</div>
```

This my .js

```
import { Timeline, DataSet } from 'vis-timeline';

Template.kk.onRendered(() => {
  const container = $('#visualization');
  const items = new DataSet([
    { id: 1, content: 'item 1', start: '2014-04-20' },
    { id: 2, content: 'item 2', start: '2014-04-14' },
    { id: 3, content: 'item 3', start: '2014-04-18' },
    {
      id: 4, content: 'item 4', start: '2014-04-16', end: '2014-04-19',
    },
    { id: 5, content: 'item 5', start: '2014-04-25' },
    {
      id: 6, content: 'item 6', start: '2014-04-27', type: 'point',
    },
  ]);
  const options = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '30px',
    margin: {
      item: 20,
    },
  };
  const tl = new Timeline(container[0], items, options);
  console.log('tl');
  console.log(tl);
});
```

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGV4v.jpg) is what I get.

Any idea why it is not being rendering correctly?

Thank's for your help

Comment: Hi and welcome on StackOverflow. You have provided what you get, so please give us your expectations of proper result as well. Tell us what's wrong with your rendering.

Comment: Hi Walter, thanks for your comment. I'm expecting this https://almende.github.io/vis/examples/timeline/basicUsage.html

Comment: Looks like a CSS problem, you need to import the VIS timeline css file somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. As Mikkel stated, it was a CSS problem.

I paste you the .js code including the imports.

```
import { Timeline, DataSet } from 'vis-timeline';
import 'vis-timeline/lib/timeline/component/css/animation.css';
import 'vis-timeline/lib/timeline/component/css/currenttime.css';
import 'vis-timeline/lib/timeline/component/css/customtime.css';
import 'vis-timeline/lib/timeline/component/css/dataaxis.css';
import 'vis-timeline/lib/timeline/component/css/item.css';
import 'vis-timeline/lib/timeline/component/css/itemset.css';
import 'vis-timeline/lib/timeline/component/css/labelset.css';
import 'vis-timeline/lib/timeline/component/css/panel.css';
import 'vis-timeline/lib/timeline/component/css/pathStyles.css';
import 'vis-timeline/lib/timeline/component/css/timeaxis.css';
import 'vis-timeline/lib/timeline/component/css/timeline.css';

Template.kk.onRendered(() => {
  const container = $('#visualization');
  const items = new DataSet([
    { id: 1, content: 'item 1', start: '2014-04-20' },
    { id: 2, content: 'item 2', start: '2014-04-14' },
    { id: 3, content: 'item 3', start: '2014-04-18' },
    {
      id: 4, content: 'item 4', start: '2014-04-16', end: '2014-04-19',
    },
    { id: 5, content: 'item 5', start: '2014-04-25' },
    {
      id: 6, content: 'item 6', start: '2014-04-27', type: 'point',
    },
  ]);
  const options = {};
  const tl = new Timeline(container[0], items, options);
  console.log('tl');
  console.log(tl);
});
```

Thanks for the help!